# Linux FTP alternative for single application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

I have a dedicated ubuntu 10.4 LTS x64 server running with:

- nginx webserver
- Php
- mysql community
- mongodb

The webserver will be running a single web application, I don't share the server with anyone I am the only one that has access to it. I don't want to use FTP since it will take extra resources for nothing, I know I can stop the daemon after I finished uploading the source code, don't suggest me that please.

Is there an alternative to ftp to upload the source code for the application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OpenSSH can do scp, which is better anyway, and you will likely have it installed for other admin purposes.

Answer (score 5):

You could use sftp which works just like ftp except everything is transferred over a secure connection and it will use sshd which is already running.  If you use windows, winscp and filezilla both support sftp.

Answer (score 0):

Try [uber uploader](http://uber-uploader.sourceforge.net/) if you just need a tool for occasional uploads.  Protect it with https or at least HTTP digest authentication.